# Replace Fragment based on click from Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have a list view of `Item`. On Click, I would like to replace the one fragment in my activity with a new fragment based on the item position of the clicked item in the listview. What is the method for doing such? There is an intent I can specify on the `Item`, but I do not wish to start a new activity, merely change the fragment in the current activity.

Answer (score 1):

If your using adapter to display the list items, then use tags to item view.

```
view.setTag(fragmentObject). // each item will hold different fragment
```

// When an item clicked, use getTag().

```
Fragment fragmentObject = (Fragment)view.getTag;
```

// and then replace the existing fragment.

```
FragmentTransaction.replace(fragmentObject).
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Comment: I think I like this approach, but is that what tags are made for?

Comment: I mostly use tags for view holder object.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing the following:

- Create your fragments (depends on how many different items are in your list)
- Then, using the click event, get the position of the list item and
- Get the correct fragment from the list and set it using the fragment manager.

**Note**
What you could do is see if the fragment can be reused (depends on what you want the user to see when they click that item from the list.

Consider:

```
public List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>(){{

    add(new FragmentA());
    add(new FragmentB());
    add(new FragmentC());
}}
```

Now, inside onClick method of your list:

```
public void setFragment(Fragment f, String tag){
    //do all the necessary steps here to set fragment
}

setFragment(fragments.get(position), "frag1");
```

So, you will be setting the correct fragment depending on which item was clicked in the list.

I hope this helps;

NOTE: Consider using Interfaces too!

Comment: Thanks, do you know if this is the best method? It seems a little odd to have to use an indexed list that is all. It would be nice if the Item itself were responsible for knowing it's fragment.

Comment: That is a good point. However, if you can determine ahead of time what TYPE of information is going to be displayed by the fragment and you know that it is the same for all items in the list, you can just use one fragment and avoid the list. I don't know any other way of making the list item responsible for its own fragment; how do you pack that information into a dynamic list?

Comment: Here is another suggestion that could work without a list of fragments: Inside onClick method, do a switch statement and case position then instantiate each fragment and set before the break statement; that way, you will not need a list at all;

Comment: The list items have an intent, which makes me think they should be able to know which fragment they are responsible for since it is somewhat similar.

Comment: Why do the list items have intents? You only really need an intent if you are starting a new activity or if another activity start the current activity.

Comment: Item is not my own class, it is in android http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.Item.html and it has an Intent as a constructor arg

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49978/discussion-between-eenvincible-and-stevebot)